Aggregate logstash message from multiple entries into only one (stack trace)
I've been struggling to find a solution to this problem. Maybe someone can shed a light on it.
All of our containers (Openshift) messages are posted to a Kafka topic, which feeds Logstash with json messages. Due to this scenario, I can't use the multiline codec to join lines matching some pattern.
I am trying to come up with an aggregation that would merge all related messages into only one (stack trace is one example), but so far I couldn't figure this out. I didn't write any piece of code yet because I have no freaking idea how to tackle this.
I can't add or change anything in the infrastructure, I can't add Filebeat in the process, for example. All I can do is change the Logstash configuration.
Any comments, ideas or insights are much appreciated. Thanks.

Could you use Kafka Streams to aggregate data to a different topic for logstash? Or better, can your apps be configured to log JSON on their own? Then the stacktrace should be one message. Otherwise, there's no reasonable information beyond a timestamp and a pod id to determine "related" messages.

Everything is already under a topic for logstash. The deal is to aggregate lines of a stack trace in one document. And no, I can't change anything but the logstash configuration.
